# Mongodb: Add to field from subarray that matches a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database in which documents have the following structure

```
{
    "word": "apple",
    "pairs": [ [12, 2], [1, 3], [2, 11] ]
}
```

So pairs is an array of arrays with 2 elements. I have a new pair, let's say my_pair: [5, 11]. I want to query for the word apple and, if it exists, modify the pairs array as following:

If there's a pair in pairs that has pair[1] == my_pair[1]

```
pair[0] += my_pair[0]
else
push my_pair in pairs`
```

So, for the particular example, the document will look like this:

```
{
    "word": "apple",
    "pairs": [ [12, 2], [1, 3], [7, 11] ]
}
```

I'm using pymongo, but I want to do this from the query, not in python code because that would require knowing the pairs array before the update and that would be an additional query. Can you please tell me what the upsert would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Nested array updates can be a problem with MongoDB, but this is okay since you only need to know the positional index of the "outer" array element to match, and you know the position of the index you want to update or rather increment via [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

The matching part is done via [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with other use of the "dot notation" form used by MongoDB and the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator:

```
db.collection.update(
    { "word": "apple", "pairs": { "$elemMatch": { "1": 11 } } },
    { "$inc": { "pairs.$.0": 5 } }
)
```

So that will match an inner array element that has "11" in the second or "1" array position, and increments at the position of the matching element in the first or "0" array position.

And of course your result is:

```
{ 
    "word" : "apple",
    "pairs" : [ [ 12, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 7, 11 ] ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Alternatively, this part can also be done with the $in operator. Is there a way to tackle the else part? Meaning if, for the given example my_pair were [2, 8], that query would return nothing because there is no subarray in the array pairs for which "1": 8. In this case I'd like to push [2, 8] in the array. Is there a way to do this too?

Comment: @CosminStanescu Things like `$addToSet` won't be of help here as from your example `[5,11]` did not exist and only the `11` part does. So really you have two updates, one to try and increment and if nothing is modified to push the array. I cannot be one step. But really this is another question, so if you have another question then please post as another question.